# Summing Conditionally Based on Secondary Column

Tags: sql, sum, case, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm having a difficult time finding information to sum a column conditionally and not sum the column if the condition isn't met.  In the following query I'm attempting to sum items that have a LineItemID that matches an ID with a leading zero.  So in the query below I'm attempting to sum the LineItemIDs 3404 and 03404 into a single row without summing the other selected ID.  This double column solution I adapted but doesn't appear to even firing correctly:

```
With LeadingZeroCombinedTransactions AS
(
    SELECT TransactionJournalDetail."TLI_ScanCode" As LineItemID, 
    StockInventory."INV_ScanCode" As ID, 
    StockInventory."INV_Name" As Name, 
    TransactionJournalDetail."TLI_ReceiptAlias" As Alias,
    TransactionJournalDetail."ASC_PK" AS Alt,
    SUM(TransactionJournalDetail."TLI_Quantity") As Quantity

    FROM ( ( ( "ecrs"."TJ_StockInventory" StockInventory 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "ecrs"."TJ_Brands" Brands ON StockInventory."INV_BRD_FK" = Brands."BRD_PK" ) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "ecrs"."TJ_Departments" Departments ON StockInventory."INV_DPT_FK" = Departments."DPT_PK" ) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "ecrs"."TJ_TransactionJournalDetail" TransactionJournalDetail ON StockInventory."INV_PK" = TransactionJournalDetail."INV_PK" )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "ecrs"."TJ_TransactionJournal" TransactionJournal ON "TransactionJournalDetail"."TJD_TRN_FK" = TransactionJournal."TRJ_TRN_FK"

    GROUP BY ID, Name, Alias, Alt,LineItemID
    ORDER BY ID DESC
)

SELECT LineItemID AS LineItemID, ID AS ID, Name, Alias,

      SUM( CASE WHEN LineItemID = STRING('0', ID)
         THEN LeadingZeroCombinedTransactions.Quantity else 0 end ) as FirstQuantity,
      SUM( CASE WHEN LineItemID = STRING('0', ID)
         THEN 0 else LeadingZeroCombinedTransactions.Quantity end ) as SecondQuantity

FROM LeadingZeroCombinedTransactions
WHERE ((ID='03404         ')
OR (ID='894773001018  '))
GROUP BY LineItemID,Name, ID, Alias
```

Leads to this result:

```
+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|   LineItemID   |        ID        |               Name               |               Alias                | FirstQuantity | SecondQuantity |
+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| '894773001018' | '894773001018  ' | 'Natural Diet Cola             ' | 'ZEVIA-SODA DIET COLA 12OZ'        |        0.0000 |         3.0000 |
| '894773001018' | '894773001018  ' | 'Natural Diet Cola             ' | 'ZEVIA-COLA SF 6PK'                |        0.0000 |         1.0000 |
| '3404'         | '03404         ' | 'Lemon Thyme Whole Chicken     ' | 'DELI-CHCKN WHLE THYME LEMON NGMO' |        0.0000 |         3.0000 |
| '03404'        | '03404         ' | 'Lemon Thyme Whole Chicken     ' | 'DELI-CHCKN LEMON THYME WHLE NGMO' |        0.0000 |        91.0000 |
+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

However, this is the desired result that I am having a really hard time getting to (summing four/five digit IDS that either have or are missing a leading zero):

```
+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------+
|   LineItemID   |        ID        |               Name               |               Alias                |    Quantity    |
+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------+
| '894773001018' | '894773001018  ' | 'Natural Diet Cola             ' | 'ZEVIA-SODA DIET COLA 12OZ'        |         3.0000 |
| '894773001018' | '894773001018  ' | 'Natural Diet Cola             ' | 'ZEVIA-COLA SF 6PK'                |         1.0000 |
| '03404'        | '03404         ' | 'Lemon Thyme Whole Chicken     ' | 'DELI-CHCKN LEMON THYME WHLE NGMO' |        94.0000 |
+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Whatever summing method I have tried I either end up summing the item I do not intend to sum ("894773001018") or not summing the item I do intend to sum ("03404").

Really struggling here to find a solution.  I'd prefer to not need to add another two columns and just sum conditionally based off of whether or not the item has a leading zero, but am being confounded at every turn.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
It seems that your LineItemID and ID do not have the same format but follow the same pattern.

Fields are alphanumeric, so try to trim spaces and then replacing 0 on the left plus trim again.

```
...


SELECT TRIM(substring(TRIM(TransactionJournalDetail."TLI_ScanCode"), patindex('%[^0]%',TRIM(TransactionJournalDetail."TLI_ScanCode")),14)) As LineItemID, 
    TRIM(substring(TRIM(StockInventory."INV_ScanCode"), patindex('%[^0]%',TRIM(StockInventory."INV_ScanCode")),14)) As ID, 
...
```

Take into account that if you change this, the values you have to introduce in the WHERE clause will be

```
WHERE ((ID='3404')
OR (ID='894773001018'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Carlos.  Is there a way to conditionally cast to integer?  Some of the fields have non-numeric characters.

Comment: Thanks for the adjustment, Carlos.  I'm getting some fascinating, chaotic and unexpected results from this method.

Comment: Specifically, it's not selecting for 3404 or 03404 at all.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I am able to select for 3404 specifically but it appears to be summing in an unanticipated way.  Sorry, but it's hard to be more specific without posting the output, but basically it appears to be summing from other non-related line items.

Comment: At least the leading 0 is functional and doing something, even if the information is chaotic.  I'm greatful for that!